# Access database, Sql query , Error "Syntax error in DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX."

Tags: t-sql

This is the query , running this in C#.
n getting above error

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `NATIONAL_ID_ISSUANCE_CENTER`; 
CREATE TABLE `NATIONAL_ID_ISSUANCE_CENTER` (
  `ID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `NAME` VARCHAR(100), 
  `APPLICATION_ID` INTEGER, 
  `STATUS` INTEGER, 
  `CREATED_BY` INTEGER, 
  `UPDATED_BY` INTEGER, 
  `CREATED_DATE` DATETIME, 
  `UPDATED_DATE` DATETIME, 
  `THIRD_PARTY_ID` INTEGER, 
  `PROVINCE_ID` INTEGER, 
  INDEX (`APPLICATION_ID`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
  INDEX (`PROVINCE_ID`), 
  INDEX (`THIRD_PARTY_ID`)
)"
```

Comment: I suspect your question has been downvoted because it shows a lack of research effort.  What steps have you taken to debug this error?  Have you been able to figure out which statement is raising the error?  Here are the Microsoft docs on the [DROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173790.aspx) and [CREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) statements.

Comment: Yes, I run the query in MS Access , n it highlights "IF EXISTS", "AUTO_INCREMENT" and "INDEX",

Comment: Microsoft office access version is 2007, I've also tried" drop table if exists " separately, but it always gives syntax error at IF EXISTS

Comment: I only want to make sure table doesn't get created twice. 
No drop is required. This above query is of MySQL syntax. and I need MS-Access syntax query of following requirement.
"Only create table if its not already created"
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an IF statement inside Drop and Create statements. Anytime you want to drop a table that you're not sure exists, use the following:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('[Database].[Schema].[TableName]') is not null)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [Database].[Schema].[TableName];
    END;
```

Please note you should replace [Database], [Schema], and [TableName] with the appropriate database, schema, and table names, respectively.

Comment: Got error while running this query. Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT','PROCEDURE' , 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE.'

Comment: [According the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173790.aspx) SQL Server 2016 supports 'IF EXISTS', which is a welcome update to tSQL. You need to tell MSAccess that your query won't return any records. You may also need to use a pass through query (it's been a while, I cannot remember off the top of my head). I'll test and update later.

Comment: Yes you need to choose [Pass-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/tbzed15h(v=vs.80).aspx) as the query type.  Update the *Returns Records* property to *False*.  You'll also need to update your create statement.  The tSQL syntax differs from MySQL.  Here are the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), with include working examples.